# Get appropriate date with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where I track the duration of watched films by a user for each day.
Now I would like to calculate a unique view count based on date.

So the conditions are:

- For each user max view count is 1
- View = 1 if one user's SUM(duration) >= 120
- Date should be fixed once SUM(duration) reaches 120

But the issue is here to get a correct date row. For example `row1.duration + row2.duration >= 120` and thus view count = 1 should be applied for `2021-10-16`

```
| id | user_id | duration | created_at | film_id |
+----+---------+----------+------------+---------+
| 1  | 1       | 80       | 2021-10-15 | 1       |
| 2  | 1       | 70       | 2021-10-16 | 1       |
| 3  | 1       | 200      | 2021-10-17 | 2       |
| 4  | 2       | 50       | 2021-10-18 | 1       |
| 5  | 2       | 90       | 2021-10-18 | 1       |
| 6  | 3       | 140      | 2021-10-18 | 2       |
| 7  | 4       | 10       | 2021-10-19 | 3       |
```

Expected result:

```
| cnt   | created_at |
+-------+------------+
| 0     | 2021-10-15 |
| 1     | 2021-10-16 |
| 0     | 2021-10-17 |
| 2     | 2021-10-18 |
| 0     | 2021-10-19 |
```

This is what I tried, but it choses first date, and ignores 0 count.
Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f786ec/15) with populated data

```
SELECT count(*) AS cnt,
         created_at
FROM 
    (SELECT user_id,
         sum(duration) AS total,
         created_at
    FROM watch_time
    GROUP BY  user_id) AS t
WHERE t.total >= 120
GROUP BY  created_at;
```

Is there any chance to have this work via SQL or it's should be done in application level?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

Version: AWS RDS MySQL 5.7.33

But I'm ok to switch to Postgres if that can help.

Much appreciated even there is a way to have MIN(date) but with the all dates(included 0 views).

Better than this one.

```
SELECT IFNULL(cnt, 0) as cnt,
         t3.created_at
FROM 
    (SELECT count(*) AS cnt,
         created_at
    FROM 
        (SELECT user_id,
         sum(duration) AS total,
         created_at
        FROM watch_time
        GROUP BY  user_id) AS t
        WHERE t.total >= 120
        GROUP BY  created_at) AS t2
    RIGHT JOIN 
    (SELECT distinct(created_at)
    FROM watch_time) AS t3
    ON t2.created_at = t3.created_at;
```

which returns:

```
| cnt   | created_at |
+-------+------------+
| 1     | 2021-10-15 |
| 0     | 2021-10-16 |
| 0     | 2021-10-17 |
| 2     | 2021-10-18 |
| 0     | 2021-10-19 |
```

But I'm not sure whether the date(2021-10-15) has taken randomly or its always the lowest date

**Update 2**:

Is it possible to include the film_id as well? Like considering user_id, film_id as a unique view instead of only grouping by user_id.

So in this case:

`row1` & `row2` both has `user_id: 1` and `film_id: 1`, and the result is 1 view, because the sum of their `durations is >= 120`. so the date in this case will be `2021-10-16`.

but `row3` has `user_id: 1` and `film_id: 2`, and with `duration >= 120` it's also a 1 view with date `2021-10-17`

```
| id | user_id | duration | created_at | film_id |
+----+---------+----------+------------+---------+
| 1  | 1       | 80       | 2021-10-15 | 1       |
| 2  | 1       | 70       | 2021-10-16 | 1       |
| 3  | 1       | 200      | 2021-10-17 | 2       |
| 4  | 2       | 50       | 2021-10-18 | 1       |
| 5  | 2       | 90       | 2021-10-18 | 1       |
| 6  | 3       | 140      | 2021-10-18 | 2       |
| 7  | 4       | 10       | 2021-10-19 | 3       |
```

Expected result:

```
| cnt   | created_at |
+-------+------------+
| 0     | 2021-10-15 |
| 1     | 2021-10-16 |
| 1     | 2021-10-17 |
| 2     | 2021-10-18 |
| 0     | 2021-10-19 |
```

Comment: What is your mysql version?

Comment: I believe you'll need a recursive query to achieve this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive

Comment: Updated the post. version 5.7.33

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using MySQL variables, it can implement your count logic, it basically orders the table rows by user_id and created_at, and calculate row by row

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/569088/14

```
SELECT created_at, SUM(CASE WHEN duration >= 120 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) counts
FROM (
  SELECT user_id, created_at, 
  CASE WHEN @UID != user_id THEN @SUM_TIME := 0 WHEN @SUM_TIME >= 120 AND @DT != created_at THEN @SUM_TIME := 0 - duration ELSE 0 END SX,
  @SUM_TIME := @SUM_TIME + duration AS duration,
  @UID := user_id,
  @DT := created_at
  FROM watch_time
  JOIN ( SELECT @SUM_TIME :=0, @DT := NOW(), @UID := '' ) t
  ORDER BY user_id, created_at
) f
GROUP BY created_at
```

Comment: Hi @ProGu! I added a record for user 1 on 2021-10-15 in your [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12ec12/1) and your query count twice user 1 (in distinct dates); I think it is not correct, let me know if I wrong and I misunderstood the requirement.

Comment: @ProGu thanks, it covers all my cases! Is it possible to include film_id as well? Like calculate views based on user_id, film_id and created_at

Comment: Hi @nachospiu result depends on the duration for your added record

Comment: @Serg by including film_id, do you mean the max count per user will be up to the number of films instead of current 1, it's better you provide sample inputs and expected output for better understanding

Comment: @ProGu updated the post. thanks in advance!

Comment: @Serg check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3b916/2

Comment: @ProGu thank you! works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I think I misunderstood the requirement in my first attempt.

**Second attempt**

**MySql >= 8.0 (or `Postgresl`) using `window functions`**

I know you are working with `MySql 5.7`, I add an answer for it next.

I am not sure if I understand correctly your requirement. Do you want the cumulative sum of time watch by user and the first time some user exceed 119 minutes count one that day?

First, I get cumulative sum by user (`cte` subquery) ordered by date. In subquery `cte1` with a CASE statement I set one the first time a user reach 120 minutes (`view` column). Finally I group by created_at (date) and count() ones in `view` column:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *, SUM(duration) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at ASC, film_id) as cum_duration
              FROM watch_time),
              
     cte1 AS (SELECT *, CASE WHEN cum_duration >= 120 AND COALESCE(LAG(cum_duration) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at ASC), 0) < 120 THEN 1 END AS view 
              FROM cte)

SELECT created_at, COUNT(view) AS cnt
FROM cte1
GROUP BY created_at;
```

| created_at | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-10-15 | 0 |
| 2021-10-16 | 1 |
| 2021-10-17 | 0 |
| 2021-10-18 | 2 |
| 2021-10-19 | 0 |

**MySql 5.7**

I get the cumulative sum for each user and filter cumulative duration >= 120, then I `group by user_id` and get `MIN(created_at)`. Finally I group by `min_created_at` and count records.

```
SELECT min_created_at AS date, count(*) AS cnt

FROM (SELECT user_id, MIN(created_at) AS min_created_at

    FROM (SELECT wt1.user_id, wt1.created_at, SUM(wt2.duration) AS cum_duration
        FROM (SELECT user_id, created_at, SUM(duration) AS duration FROM watch_time GROUP BY user_id, created_at) wt1
        INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id, created_at, SUM(duration) AS duration FROM watch_time GROUP BY user_id, created_at) wt2 ON wt1.user_id = wt2.user_id AND wt1.created_at >= wt2.created_at 
        GROUP BY wt1.user_id, wt1.created_at
        HAVING SUM(wt2.duration) >= 120) AS sq

    GROUP BY user_id) AS sq2
GROUP BY min_created_at;
```

| date | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-10-16 | 1 |
| 2021-10-18 | 2 |

You can JOIN my query (RIGHT JOIN) with the original table (GROUP BY created_at) to get the rest of the dates with count equal to 0.

**First attempt**

I understood that you want count one each time a user reach 120 minutes per day.

First, I get the total movie watch time by user and date (subquery sq), then with a `CASE` statement I set one each time a user in a date exceed 119 minutes, I group by `created_at` (date) and `count()` ones in `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT created_at, COUNT(CASE WHEN total_duration >= 120 THEN 1 END) cnt
FROM (SELECT created_at, user_id, SUM(duration) AS total_duration
             FROM watch_time
             GROUP BY created_at, user_id) AS sq
GROUP BY created_at;
```

**Output** (with sample data from the question):

| reated_at | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-10-15 | 0 |
| 2021-10-16 | 0 |
| 2021-10-17 | 1 |
| 2021-10-18 | 2 |
| 2021-10-19 | 0 |

Comment: @Squirrel.98 you are right! I recognized I misunderstood the problem, so if someone let me know that I can improve my answer.

Comment: @nachospiu I'm not the one who down vote, but your updated version works. thanks

Comment: @nachospiu I eventually understood your updated approach... it's amazing... you have my respect! I wish I could accept 2 answers